# SQL Server / Report Builder subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I'm struggling to figure out why a subquery in report builder is returning more than one row.

```
(
    SELECT 
    (
        CASE
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('50089079','50089080') THEN 'L2 Maths FS'
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('50089067','50089109') THEN 'L1 Maths FS'
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('50084987','50092959') THEN 'E3 Maths FS'
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('50084975','50091967') THEN 'E2 Maths FS'
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('50084963','50091724') THEN 'E1 Maths FS'
            WHEN C.CourseCode IN ('60146084') THEN 'GCSE Maths'
            Else 'NA'
        END
    )
    FROM
        Enrolment E
    INNER JOIN 
        Course C ON C.CourseID = E.CourseID
    WHERE 
        E.PMStudentID = vReports_Enrolment.PMStudentID
        AND C.CourseCode IN ('50089079', '50089080', '50089067', '50089109', '50084987', '50092959', '50084975', '50091967', '50084963', '50091724', '60146084')
        AND vReports_Enrolment.CompletionID = 1
)
```

This is the data for a specific learner where this error is popping up - I've highlighted where there would usually be 2 rows returned if not for the CompletionID being checked to see if it's '1':

```
CourseCode  CompletionID  
-------------------------
50044357    1 
50044369    1
50089079    0   
60146084    1
60187578    1
60148366    1
```

The expected behavior in this case is to return 'GCSE Maths'  - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The current output you posted does not directly correspond to the query which sits above it.  Can you edit your question?  With regard to your error, it is pretty self-explanatory.  You have a subquery in a select clause which returns more than one record/value, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The overall query is enormous, and it's just this part that falls over. I would expect, based on the CASE that it would return exactly 1 value if the CourseCode is in the range specified and its CompletionID is 1.

Comment: We need to see the _entire_ query.  Yes a single `CASE` expression in a select clause should not be triggering this error, which is why this likely is not the problem.

Comment: Just added `TOP 1` to the select... seems to work -shrug-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added:

```
(
    SELECT TOP 1
    (
        CASE
```

Ensure only one row is returned, which is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you have two rows or more rows.

Using TOP 1 will only choose the first which is no guarantee that it's the one you want, especially if your data is not as clean as you think.

It is safer to use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` . That way, if all returned rows are the same, just duplicates, then you will get the correct answer. If you still get an error then you need to investigate the sub-query results.